# How to migrate from express js to feathers js server?

Tags: feathersjs

I build an api rest by express js simply to post an data in my server .

```
app.post("/register", function(request, response){
   var username = request.body.username;
});
```

How i can do this with feathersjs ? and how i can call it from my reactjs app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feathers is a [drop-in replacement for Express](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html). That means you can replace your `const app = express();` with `const app = feathers()` and everything will work just the same, so what you are showing above you can also do with Feathers.

The real Feathers way to accomplish this however is through [services](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html) which - with the other important concepts - are described in the [basics guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/step-by-step/readme.html).

There are pre-build services [for several databases](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html) (which can be customized through [hooks](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html)) but you can [always create your own service](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html). It is important to note that Feathers services - unlike the Express middleware you showed - will be available via HTTP (REST) *and* websockets (which also gets you real-time events). See [here how service methods map to REST endpoints](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/rest.html).

Your example in Feathers simply looks like this:

```
app.use('/register', {
  create(data, params) {
    // data is the request body e.g.
    // data.username

    // Always return a promise with the result data
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  }  
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend :)

Comment: Daff , please have you an idea how to authenticate login (username and password ) by feathers-authentication ?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation at https://docs.feathersjs.com (https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/auth/readme.html, https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/chat/authentication.html, https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/server.html etc.). We are happy to help with any more specific problems that might come up.

Comment: I read these docs but i don't undrstand . please have you an complete tutorial ?

Comment: The chat guide at https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/chat/readme.html# is a complete tutorial. If you have specific questions, the folks in the Slack channel at http://slack.feathersjs.com/ are always very helpful.